# Как сделать резиновый spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

У меня есть spinner, и я не знаю как сделать его "резиновым", его ширина определяется по самому длинному элементу. А так же я имею 2 layout'а для диалога и самого spinner'a

> **city_item.xml (spinner)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_city_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

> **city_items.xml (dialog)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_city_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

> **Ну и собственно сам Spinner**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#173649"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|top">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_go_home"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_filter"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/filter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Результат таков: видно на заднем фоне что Москва не по центру**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Э-э-э... `android:layout_width="match_parent"`?

Comment: А спиннер-то где на скриншоте?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja на скриншоте в тулбаре написано Москва